# Using buffered renderer for grid in extjs

Tags: extjs, grid, buffer, paging

I'm looking to load a pretty big dataset (around 20k rows) and use the extjs 4.2 grid buffered rendering to view the data.  I've seen so many examples that are different (extjs 4.2 examples) that my head is spinning and I can't get any of them to work.  There is even an extjs page http://www.sencha.com/blog/first-look-at-ext-js-4-2-grid that shows how simple buffered rendering is in extjs 4.2 (just add the buffered rendering plugin to the grid ) but the examples in the sdk don't look like the example on the web page (they still use the stores buffering configs even though the linked to page above explicitly says you don't need to do that in extjs 4.2).

In the end ... I don't want to hit the server over and over and buffer the data that way.  I want to load all the data and just buffer the grid's current dataset.

Does anybody know of an example of how to make that happen ?

Comment: The example here has a local dataset and loads it once: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/grid/buffer-grid.html

Comment: Thank you... I had not run across that example yet.  I'll see if I can get that puppy running.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my english is not so good.
Also, if I understood your question on the right way, you have to learn the difference between Remote- and Local Filtering. I think what you search is a local filter,
there you can set individual parameters as you want.

take a look to [this](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html) example, on the button of the grid, you can find buttons to switch between local- and remote filters, there you got a working example for local filtering. Should do what you want :)